# Error when building Webpack 2 project. WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, postcss

Made migration from Webpack 1 to Webpack 2 and getting an error when trying to built project:

```
C:\..\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:19
            throw new 

WebpackOptionsValidationError(webpackOptionsValidationErrors);
                ^

WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'postcss'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, record
sPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           postcss: ...
         }
       })
     ]
    at webpack (C:\..\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:19:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\..\webpack.devserver.js:8:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Already have no idea what else I need to do. If somebody knows how to fix this problem I'd be really appreciate!

I have following structure:

```
- client
- node_modules
- webpack.config.babel
-- index.js
-- webpack.loaders.js
-- webpack.plugins.js
-- webpack.postcss.js
- .babelrc
- webpack.config.js
- webpack.devserver.js
```

webpack.loaders.js:

```
import {extractTextPlugin} from './webpack.plugins';
const DEV = global.buildOptions.dev;

const appJsLoader = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'ng-annotate-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }],
  include: /client/,
  exclude: [/3rd-party/, /node_modules/],
};

const ejsLoader = {
  test: /\.ejs$/,
  loader: 'ejs-loader'
};

const rawJsLoader = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  use: [],
  include: [/3rd-party/, /node_modules/],
  exclude: /client/
};

const thirdPartyStyleLoader = {
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: [/node_modules/],
  use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } }
    ]
  })
};
const thirdPartyStyleLoaderMDI = {
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: [/3rd-party/],
  use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } }
    ]
  })
};

const commonStyleLoader = {
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: /client/,
  exclude: [/3rd-party/, /node_modules/],
  use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
      'postcss-loader'
    ]
  })
};

const imagesLoader = {
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
};

const sassLoader = {
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
      'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'
    ]
  })
};

const HTMLLoader = {
  test: /\.html$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=md-icon:md-svg-src'
};

export default [
  appJsLoader,
  rawJsLoader,
  ejsLoader,
  thirdPartyStyleLoader,
  thirdPartyStyleLoaderMDI,
  commonStyleLoader,
  HTMLLoader,
  imagesLoader,
  sassLoader,
  {
    test: /\.woff$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=[name].[ext]'
  },
  {
    test: /\.woff2$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=[name].[ext]'
  },
  {
    test: /\.[ot]tf$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=[name].[ext]'
  },
  {
    test: /\.eot$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=[name].[ext]'}

];
```

webpack.plugins.js:

```
import webpack, { optimize } from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

const DEV = global.buildOptions.dev;
const globals = {
    __ENV__: `"${global.buildOptions.env}"`,
    __DEV__: String(DEV),
    __DESKTOP__: !!global.buildOptions.desktop,
    __API_URL__: JSON.stringify(global.buildOptions.publicPath || '/')
};

const devPlugins = [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
];
// export const extractTextPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css');
export const extractTextPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].css'
  // disable: false,
  // allChunks: true
});

const prodPlugins = [
    extractTextPlugin,
    new optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        mangle: false
    }),
    // new optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()
];


export default [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(globals),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        favicon: './client/app/assets/icons/ngb-logo.png',
        template: './client/index.html.ejs',
        inject: 'body'
    }),
    function () { // sets build to failure if a compilation error occurred
        this.plugin("done", function (stats) {
            if (stats.compilation.errors && stats.compilation.errors.length) {
                console.log(stats.compilation.errors);
                process.exit(1);
            }
        });
    },
    ...(DEV ? devPlugins : prodPlugins)
];
```

index.js:

```
import path from 'path';

import loaders from './webpack.loaders';

export {default as plugins} from './webpack.plugins';
export {default as postcss} from './webpack.postcss';

const DEV = global.buildOptions.dev;

export const context = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

export const entry = (() => {
    const items = {

        app: [
            'expose?$!jquery',
            'expose?jQuery!jquery',
            './client/babel-polyfill-custom.js',
            'jquery-mousewheel',
            'babel-polyfill',
            './client/app/app.js'
        ]
    };

    return items;
})();

export const output = {
    path: path.resolve(context, 'dist'),
    publicPath: global.buildOptions.publicPath || '/',
    // desktopBuild: !!global.buildOptions.desktop,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[name].js'
};
export const resolve = {
    alias: {
        'pixi.js': 'pixi.js/bin/pixi.js',
    }
};
export const devtool = DEV ? 'source-map' : undefined;
export const module = {rules: loaders};
export const cache = DEV;
```

webpack.postcss.js:

```
const DEV = global.buildOptions.dev;

export default [
    require('postcss-import')(),
    require('postcss-cssnext')({
        browsers: DEV
            ? ['Chrome >= 45']
            : [
            'Android 2.3',
            'Android >= 4',
            'Chrome >= 20',
            'Firefox >= 24',
            'Explorer >= 10',
            'iOS >= 6',
            'Opera >= 12',
            'Safari >= 6'
        ]
    })
]
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }], "node8"],
  "plugins": ["syntax-flow", "transform-flow-strip-types", "add-module-exports"]
}
```

devDependencies in pakage.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "8.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-node8": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-regenerator-runtime": "latest",
    "babel-register": "latest",
    "core-js": "2.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "ejs-loader": "0.2.1",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flow-vars": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.40.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "minimist": "latest",
    "ng-annotate-loader": "0.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "postcss-cssnext": "3.0.2",
    "postcss-import": "11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.9",
    "postcss-normalize": "4.0.0",
    "pug-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "sass-lint": "^1.8.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "transform-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5",
    "worker-loader": "1.1.0"
  }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
require("babel-core/register");
require('babel-polyfill');
global.buildOptions = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
global.buildOptions.dev = !global.buildOptions.prodBuild;

module.exports = require('./webpack.config.babel/');
```

webpack.devserver.js:

```
const port = 8080;
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./webpack.config');
for (const key of Object.keys(config.entry))
    config.entry[key].unshift(`webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${port}/`, "webpack/hot/dev-server");

config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
const compiler = webpack(config);
const DevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');

new DevServer(compiler, {
    contentBase: './dist',

    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    quiet: false,
    noInfo: false,
    lazy: false,

    stats: {
        assets: false,
        colors: true,
        version: true,
        hash: false,
        timings: true,
        chunks: false,
        chunkModules: false
    }
})
    .listen(port, "localhost", () => console.log('webpack dev server started on http://localhost:8080'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a file called `postcss.config.js` to pass the config for PostCSS, just put it at the root of your project. Correct me if I'm wrong, I can't find any mention of `webpack.postcss.js` online.

`postcss.config.js` should look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-smart-import')(),
    require('precss')(),
    require('autoprefixer')(),
  ]
};
```

For other options refer to the [PostCSS github page](https://github.com/postcss/postcss)